# Laravel 3 Models combined through one table? (Many-To-Many ?)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I just cannot wrap my head around this and even though there are already some answers out there, I wasnt able to build what I want.

My Problem
I have 3 Models.

- User
- Topic (like a blog post)
- Reaction (e.g. Like, Laugh, Cry).

What i basicly want to do is:
One topic can have several reactions from several users. So a many to many relationship combining 3 models instead of the regular 2.

For example user one reacts to the topic with a like and a laugh.

In a perfect world this would come down to one connecting pivot table like so:

```
Table reaction_topic_user
user_id
topic_id
reaction_id
```

Is there a good Eloquent way to query for example which topic has which reactions including the users that made these reactions?

I dont think this is a usecase for a hasManyThrough relationship but somehow I cant seem to find a solution.

Would be amazing if someone can lead my brain in the right direction!

Comment: When you have more than 2 "primary" keys (relation IDs), then it should be treated as a normal Model (in laravel), and you just use an scope or `where`. I have no idea if there is a community package to solve this

Comment: Agreed with @matiaslauriti; in my experience, as soon as you add a 3rd FK to a pivot table, it stops being a `many-to-many` between two Models, and should be treated as a `hasMany` between the related Models; a `User` would "have many" of these `topic/reaction` combos, as would a `Topic` "have many" of them, etc. There's a ["hasManyDeep" Package](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep) that _might_ fit your needs (extends the logic on `hasManyThrough`, so maybe not; been a while since I used it), but otherwise, simple define a Model for this Table and setup the relationships.

Comment: Maybe in Laravel 10 or 11, someone introduces some sort of "hasMany" for 3 keys, or maybe whatever amount of keys to prevent having to define a Model and then use a `where` or a scope. I did not have to do this many times, but I hate when I hit this same behaviour, feels dirty solving it this way

Comment: Thank you for your answers! @TimLewis but replacing that with hasMany relationships would only make sense if I start off my search from the pivot table no? In your example I would need more db queries If I want to know details of Topic or Reaction, get the Cobo first and from there get Reaction and Topic model. I really thought that there may be a single query for that :/

Comment: I could query many to many from topics to reactions using user_id as a pivot:
return $topic->belongsToMany(Reason::class)->withPivot('user_id'); But is there no way to eager load a realtionship within a pivot?

Comment: Kinda, but depends on how you visualize it. If you named your table `interactions` and Model `Interaction` (as an example), then a `User` can "have many" `Interactions`, while each `Interaction` belongs to a `User`, a `Topic` and a`Reaction`. It would be the same if you started from `User`, `Topic` or `Reaction`; `User 1:N Interaction(s) 1:1 User | Topic | Reaction`, `Topic 1:N Interaction(s) 1:1 User | Topic | Reaction`, and so on (unless I'm horribly mistaken). And you got it; `->withPivot()` can load columns, but not Relationships.

Comment: And sorry yes, for Querying, you have to do something like `User::withWhereHas('interactions', function ($subQuery) { return $subQuery->where('topic_id', 1); })->get()`, which would return all `User`s and their associated `interactions`, filtered and reduced to only those that have a `topic_id` of `1` (again, as an example, could use `->whereHas('topic', 1)` or similar instead, etc etc.). Logic would be the same from each Model you started from.

Comment: Alright, thank you I will try that out!